# Looking for RC2 encryption in .Net Core

Tags: encryption, asp.net-core, cryptography, .net-core, rc2-cipher

I'm tasked with writing a bridge program to encrypt some data that will be consumed by a legacy app.  The legacy app uses an old library that does RC2 encryption.  Specifically it is using a block size of 8 bytes and key size of 16 bytes.  The new program must be .Net Core.  I didn't see any such libraries available.

Before anyone asks, yes that encryption is out-dated and insecure.  No, I cannot change the legacy app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RC2 is not available in .NET Core 1.0 or 1.1. It will be available in .NET Core 2.0.

cref https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/12744. The PR added RC2 to .NET Core 2.0. This means you might be able to get this working using [daily builds](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx#daily-builds) of .NET Core.

In the meantime, you can use RC2 on .NET Framework by using the [RC2CryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rc2cryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) API.

Comment: Thanks, Nate.  Turns out I had to dig up the old VB source code and tweak the legacy app to handle the AES.